# XSLT 2.0 - Nesting Elements In Output From Non-Nested Input

Tags: xslt, position, element, xslt-2.0, counting

I'm working on a style sheet that outputs in a hierarchical from an input file with none. Every element of the input file is a sibling of one another, and each "header" element denotes a different section.

Sample input file (the actual sections under each header are about 10 times longer than this):

```
<Header>  
     Header1
</Header>
<Sub1>
     Sub1 first
</Sub1>
<Sub1>
     Sub1 second
</Sub1>
<Sub2>
     Sub2 first, Sub1 second
</Sub2>
<Sub1>
     Sub1 third
</Sub1>
<Sub2>
     Sub2 first, Sub1 third
</Sub2>

<Header>
     Header2
</Header>
Etc...
```

And the output of the above input should look like:

```
<Header>
     Header1
     <Step>
         Sub1 first
     </Step>
     <Step>
         Sub1 second
         <Step>
             Sub2 first, Sub1 second
         </Step>
     </Step>
     <Step>
         Sub1 third
         <Step>
             Sub2 first, Sub1 third
         </Step>
     </Step>
</Header>

<Header>
    Header2
    Etc.....
</Header>
```

Right now, I'm able to get the output up to the "Sub2 first, sub1 second". When I know that the next element is not another Sub2 or deeper subelement (Sub3), then I break from my Sub2 template, returning back into Sub1 template. And from here, my position variable still has the position of "Sub1 second". I have positioning information processed each time a template is called - so I have all the current position in document order for "Sub2 first, sub1 second" but once I break from the template back into Sub1's template, I lose that information. I can't seem to get the current position in document order to determine what the real next element is. A modifiable global parameter or variable would be ideal, but I know that's not possible in XSLT.

I'm not sure how to go about accomplishing this. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT 2.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <t>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="pScope" select="*"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pElemName" select="name(*[1])"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:param name="pScope"/>
  <xsl:param name="pElemName" select="'Step'"/>

    <xsl:for-each-group select="$pScope"
        group-starting-with="*[name()= name($pScope[1])]">
       <xsl:element name="{$pElemName}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[2]">
          <xsl:with-param name="pScope" select=
           "current-group()[position() > 1]"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (based on the provided, but wrapped into a top element and added one more header with different names):

```
<t>
    <Header>Header1</Header>
    <Sub1>Sub1 first</Sub1>
    <Sub1>Sub1 second</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Sub2 first, Sub1 second</Sub2>
    <Sub1>Sub1 third</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Sub2 first, Sub1 third</Sub2>
    <Header>Header2</Header>
    <x>Sub1 first</x>
    <x>Sub1 second</x>
    <y>Sub2 first, Sub1 second</y>
    <x>Sub1 third</x>
    <z>Sub2 first, Sub1 third</z>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct output**:

```
<t>
   <Header>Header1<Step>Sub1 first</Step>
      <Step>Sub1 second<Step>Sub2 first, Sub1 second</Step>
      </Step>
      <Step>Sub1 third<Step>Sub2 first, Sub1 third</Step>
      </Step>
   </Header>
   <Header>Header2<Step>Sub1 first</Step>
      <Step>Sub1 second<Step>Sub2 first, Sub1 second</Step>
      </Step>
      <Step>Sub1 third<Step>Sub2 first, Sub1 third</Step>
      </Step>
   </Header>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using `<xsl:for-each-group>` with the `group-starting-with` attribute.
2. Fine-grained processing -- templates are applied on the second element of the `current-group()` and the scope for the next grouping is passed as parameter.

Comment: Fine-grained is really nice. Thank you! How would you handle multiple elements that can all be classified as a Sub1 or Sub2, etc? For example, a Sub1 that has subelements listed after it, will have an element name of Sub1_after instead of just Sub1. Another more complicated example is for the Sub2's - the different element names are Sub2, WH, and PS - and they all need to be converted to Sub2.

Comment: @Katie: There are more than one way of doing this. I'd go for a two-pass transformation as the most simple and clear solution. In the first pass you convert all aliases to the main name, then in the second pass you apply my solution.

Comment: @Dimitre: By pass, you mean 2 seperate XSLT files where one converts equivalent elements, and the second actually processes the document?

Comment: @Katie: No, just produce the result of the 1st transformation in the body of an xsl:variable, then apply the second transformation to that variable's body (probably using a `mode` attribute on all templates used for the 2nd pass). Search for "2-pass transformation" or for "multi-pass" transformation in the "xslt" tag. In XSLT 2.0 it is even easier -- you don't use the xxx:node-set() ext. function anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to skip over certain elements using this method?

Comment: @katie: Probably yes, especially if you explain what you mean :)

Comment: @Dimitre: haha sorry - so for example, in your code above, say I wanted to skip over the X element and continue with Y and Z under the Header element.

Comment: @Katie: So, do you want just to ignore/delete any `x` element and do the grouping with the rest?

Comment: @Dimitre. Yes. But there are some instances where I need to check the element's value, if it doesn't match certain things, then I want to ignore that too - say any Y element with the word "second" in it.

Comment: @Katie: It seems that the best thing to do is to think it over well and then formulate this as a new question.

Comment: @Dimitrie: I'm sorry for the confusion! I made a completely new post... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082688/xslt-2-0-using-grouping-to-nest-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082688/xslt-2-0-using-grouping-to-nest-elements) . Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="pNames" select="'|'"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($pNames,concat('|',name(),'|')))">
            <xsl:variable name="vNext" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNext">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pNames"
                                    select="concat($pNames,name(),'|')"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNext" mode="search">
                <xsl:with-param name="pNames" select="$pNames"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pSearch" select="name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="search">
        <xsl:param name="pNames"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSearch"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($pNames,concat('|',name(),'|')))">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name()=$pSearch">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pNames" select="$pNames"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"
                                         mode="search">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pNames" select="$pNames"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pSearch" select="$pSearch"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With welformed input:

```
<root>
    <Header>Header1</Header>
    <Sub1>Sub1 first</Sub1>
    <Sub1>Sub1 second</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Sub2 first, Sub1 second</Sub2>
    <Sub1>Sub1 third</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Sub2 first, Sub1 third</Sub2>
    <Header>Header2</Header>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <Header>Header1
        <Sub1>Sub1 first</Sub1>
        <Sub1>Sub1 second
            <Sub2>Sub2 first, Sub1 second</Sub2>
        </Sub1>
        <Sub1>Sub1 third
            <Sub2>Sub2 first, Sub1 third</Sub2>
        </Sub1>
    </Header>
    <Header>Header2</Header>
</root>
```

With the name replacement and the new requeriment of one level with several names, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:r="rules"
 exclude-result-prefixes="r">
    <r:r m="|Header|">Header</r:r>
    <r:r m="|Sub1|">Step</r:r>
    <r:r m="|Sub2|">Step</r:r>
    <xsl:variable name="vRules" select="document('')/*/r:r"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="pNames" select="'|'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vName" select="concat('|',name(),'|')"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($pNames,$vName))">
            <xsl:variable name="vNext" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vMatch"
                          select="$vRules[contains(@m,$vName)]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vReplace"
                 select="concat($vMatch,name((.)[not($vMatch)]))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vSearch"
                          select="concat($vMatch/@m,$vName)"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$vReplace}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNext">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pNames"
                                    select="concat($pNames,$vSearch)"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNext" mode="search">
                <xsl:with-param name="pNames" select="$pNames"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pSearch" select="$vSearch"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="search">
        <xsl:param name="pNames"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSearch"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vName" select="concat('|',name(),'|')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pNames,$vName)"/>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pSearch,$vName)">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pNames" select="$pNames"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"
                                         mode="search">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pNames" select="$pNames"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pSearch" select="$pSearch"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <Header>Header1
        <Step>Sub1 first</Step>
        <Step>Sub1 second
            <Step>Sub2 first, Sub1 second</Step>
        </Step>
        <Step>Sub1 third
            <Step>Sub2 first, Sub1 third</Step>
        </Step>
    </Header>
    <Header>Header2</Header>
</root>
```

**Note**:  Synonyms for same level should be in `r:r/@m`

Answer (score -1):

Your input xml isn't really an xml so I added a root node. I'd advise against using xslt to do this kind of processing. But if you must - here's something to get you started.

Btw. Do your subsections have any kind of Id?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Header"/>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header">
    <Header>
      <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Root/Sub1[preceding-sibling::Header[1]/. = $current]"/>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sub1">
    <Step>
      <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Root/Sub2[preceding-sibling::Sub1[1]/. = $current]"/>
    </Step>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sub2">
    <Step>
      <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
      <!-- todo -->
    </Step>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```